# onSubmit is not defined error in React Js

Tags: reactjs

I am getting error while compiling my code actually i am trying to get the user inputs from form which is in other component.
Error: 'onSubmit' is not defined  no-undef

```
export default function Student(props) {
    this.state={
        fields:{},
    }
    onSubmit=fields=>{
       this.setState({fields});
    };

        const classes = useStyles();
        const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

        const handleOpen = () => {
          setOpen(true);
        };

        const handleClose = () => {
          setOpen(false);
        };

        return (
            <div className="mainContainer">
                <h1>Student Data</h1>
                <div className="studentTable">
                <Paper>
                    <Table >
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right"><b>Class</b></TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right"><b>Section</b></TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right"><b>Roll No.</b></TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            {props.data.map(row => (
                                <TableRow key={row.Name}>
                                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                        {row.Name}
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="right">{row.Class}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="right">{row.Section}</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="right">{row.RollNo}</TableCell>
                                </TableRow>

                            ))}

                                <TableRow>
                                <TableCell></TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </Paper>
            </div>
            <Button variant="contained"  type="button" onClick={handleOpen}>
        Add
      </Button>

      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        className={classes.modal}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={open}>
          <div className={classes.paper} >
              <div className="modalContent">
              <h2 id="transition-modal-title">Add Student</h2>
                <AddStudent onSubmit={fields=>this.onSubmit(fields)}/>
              </div>


          </div>
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
            </div>

        );

}
```

I have tried this. also but nothing working everytime getting different errors. and this my other component

class AddStudent extends Component{
     state={
         fullName:"",
         Class:"",
         Section:"",
         RollNo:""
     }

```
 change = (e)=>{
     this.setState({
        [e.target.name]:e.target.value
     });
 };

 onSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state)
    this.setState({
     fullName:"",
     Class:"",
     Section:"",
     RollNo:""
    })
 }
```

render() {

```
    return (


        <div>
            <form   >
                <TextField className="text" 
                    id="outlined-name"
                    label="Name"
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                    name="fullName"
                    value={this.state.fullName}
                   onChange={e=>this.change(e)}
                /> 
                <TextField
                className="text"
                id="outlined-name"
                label="Class"
                margin="normal"
                variant="outlined"
                name="Class"
                value={this.state.Class}
                onChange={e=>this.change(e)}

            />
             <TextField
             className="text"
                id="outlined-name"
                label="Section"
                margin="normal"
                variant="outlined"
                name="Section"
                value={this.state.Section}
                onChange={e=>this.change(e)}

            />
             <TextField
             className="text"
                id="outlined-name"
                label="Roll No"
                margin="normal"
                variant="outlined"
                name="RollNo"
                value={this.state.RollNo}
                onChange={e=>this.change(e)}
            />
            <div><Button variant="contained"  type="submit" className="addButton" onClick={e=>this.onSubmit(e)}>Add Student</Button></div>

            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

export default AddStudent;

Answer (score 1):

In `Student` component. This line will change to:

```
onSubmit=fields=>{
       this.setState({fields});
    };
```

```
const onSubmit = fields => {
  // also here you cant use this.setState as it is functional component
}
```

Also if you are going to keep this functional Component. You need to access this method directly like:

```
(fields) => onSubmit(fields)
```

**Update**

After looking into code more I think you have mixed the usage of Class and functional Component. I recommend you to please read the React docs to understand this better and also some articles on Class methods & instance.

Read this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/

Answer (score 0):

in react function component create method onSubmit like this

```
const onSubmit = (fields) => {...}
```

using

```
<button onClick={fields => onSubmit(fileds)}>Submit</button>
```